# Differential Functional Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Functional equations are some of my favorite types of math puzzles. I was wondering if anybody knows of any good (and solvable) functional equation problems that are *combined* with a differential equation. For example (though I know not the solutions or if it has any):
$$f(2x)+f''(x+1)=\sqrt{1+f'(x)}$$
Can anybody give any good examples of solvable combination functional/differential equation problems and perhaps also give me some ideas about how to solve them using non-trivial solutions (constant functions)?

Thanks!

Comment: $ f ( x ) = 1 $ is a solution to your equation.

Comment: Functional equations (except for a few very narrow classes) are generally not solvable, unless constructed specifically to be solvable. _Functional differential_ equations are by no means easier. As for the examples, follow me: let $f(x)=\sin x$. What do we know about $f(2x)$? Well, there is a formula for it. Can't we express it via... wait, that $\cos$ is also a derivative... and so we arrive at a beautiful equation: $f(2x)=2f'(x)f(x)$. Who could expect it to be solvable?